# what is the best database connectivity support library framework for c c++?

Tags: c++, c, database

tell me about the best database connectivity support library framework for c c++

Comment: The answers for C and for C++ are likely to be quite different. Please clarify which language you are looking for. Also, which platform? The answer for the Microsoft stack is likely to be different from that for a Unix/Oracle stack, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for something like [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/) as Datbase, It provides **libpq - C Library**, Which is a excellent library.

libpq is the C application programmer's interface to PostgreSQL. libpq is a set of library functions that allow client programs to pass queries to the PostgreSQL backend server and to receive the results of these queries.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SQLAPI++](http://www.sqlapi.com/).  Cross-platform, cross-db and relatively easy to use and integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's got a few quirks my favourite is [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/).

It allows you to easily apply SQL queries to Postgres, MySQL, Oracle and Sqlite backends (among others).  It's quite portable and has a fairly modern design.  Recommended!

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Debea](http://debea.net) - SQL Access and ORM for C++